# Generating a release bundle package for UWP app with react-native-windows

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, react-native, uwp, react-native-windows

I am trying to generate a release bundle package for UWP application developed using react-native-windows to upload on microsoft store. 
I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Environment:
react-native -v: v0.59.10

npm ls rnpm-plugin-windows: ^0.4.0

npm ls react-native-windows: “0.59.0-legacy.2”

node -v: 10.15.3

npm -v: 6.4.1

Using below command to generate a windows bundle file,

"react-native bundle --platform windows --entry-file index.js --bundle-output windows/project_name/ReactAssets/index.windows.bundle --assets-dest windows/project_name/ReactAsset

Debug build happens quick and able to run the app.
Release build is taking hours and getting a freeze.

Though it takes time, has anyone succeeded in generating a release build?

Does any of the solution above works completely? Found in few threads that release build can be taken, but app crashes on launch.

If there is no option, can debug build be published to store? (Worst case)

Requesting immediate attention on this.

It would be great help if anyone can help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take release build?..

Comment: Uncheck Compile with .NET Native tool chain in your app properties under Build. and try